# why might execv crash?

Tags: c, execv

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    printf("start\n");
    char *const parmList[] = {"/bin/ls", "-l", NULL};
    execv("/bin/ls", parmList);
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled with GCC4.2 Any ideas why this might crash? I'm not getting any error messages in xcode.

EDIT: user error. "crash" meant xcode froze when it ran the program. Pressing continue works fine.

Comment: That program looks fine - did you check the return status from `execv`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code runs and compiles fine in my environment, gcc 4.4.3 under Ubuntu 10. That leads me to believe that you have a different problem from the one you think you have :-)

---

```
pax@pax-desktop:~$ ./testprog
start
total 2152
drwxr-xr-x 11 pax pax    4096 2010-10-02 08:23 Pax
: :
----r-S---  1 pax pax       0 2010-08-23 18:58 xyz

pax@pax-desktop:~$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

---

Try the following code to see if the actual `exec` is failing. If it is, it should tell you why. If it isn't, then you won't see the `rc` output at all.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int rc;
    printf("start\n");
    char *const parmList[] = {"/bin/ls", "-l", NULL};
    rc = execv("/bin/ls", parmList);
    printf ("rc = %d, errno = %d\n", rc, errno);
    return 0;
}
```

Also check to make sure the `/bin/ls` is what you expect it to be (an executable, not a script, for example).

And it's worth clarifying what you mean by "crash". Is it just not producing any output? It it dumping a core file? Is it bringing your entire OS to its knees, causing a reboot?

Comment: funny. When in xcode, it freeze like I have an error. If I press continue, it works like it should.

Comment: Interesting. If "continue" is a button, you may have a breakpoint set that it's stopping on. That's one possibility. Another is that the xcode IDE may not be used to having the entire process swapped out underneath it (which `exec` does). Both of those are suppositions but possible nonetheless.